# Align scrollable content div next to fixed width div

Tags: html, css

So the situation is as follows:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="scrollable"><div id="textBox"><p>lots of text</p></div></div>
     <div id="form"><p>I am actually a form</p></div>
    </div>
```

The whole wrapper has a fixed height of 40vh while the width is not definied and therefore maxed out. Within the scrollable div there is a text box with a different background and a little bit of padding so that you actually can see it. My scrollable has a fixed minimum width. How can I achieve to display both the scrollable and the text box right next to each other? Here is what I tried:

```
    #wrapper {
      max-height: 40vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: aquamarine;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #scrollable {
      max-height: 40vh;
      order: 1;
      width:40%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10%;
    }
    #textBox {
      max-height: 25vh;
      background-color:lightseagreen;
      color: white;
      padding: 10%;
      margin: 5%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    #form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      order: 2;
    }
```

If I don't define the height for the textBox then it just doesn't care and simply overflows. This seems more like a hack so far and I really want to know how you would actually achieve something like this in a clean way.

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rd8v3jqc/1/

```css
#wrapper {
      max-height: 40vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: aquamarine;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #scrollable {
      max-height: 40vh;
      order: 1;
      width:40%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 10%;
    }
    #textBox {
      max-height: 20vh;
      background-color:lightseagreen;
      color: white;
      padding: 10%;
      margin: 5%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    #form {
      margin: 0 auto;
      order: 2;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="scrollable">
     <div id="textBox">
     <p>lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of textlots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text lots of text</p>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div id="form"><p>I am actually a form</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please put your example into something so I don't have to copy and paste your code. CodePen, JSFiddle or press `CTRL+M` to use SO's Snippet tool.

Comment: I am confused by your question: _How can I achieve to display both the scrollable and the text box right next to each other?_ The `#textBox` is nested inside the `#scrollable` but you want them next to each other?

Comment: I want to display the scrollable div next to the form. Inside the scrollable div should be the content text box with a little bit of a gap and inside the scrollable I want to be able to scorll through the whole text box.

Comment: @Jading oh ok, you want the `#scrollable` next to the `#form`

Comment: @zgood exactly, yes